# React.memo: Using custom function to compare React component props with flexibility and efficiently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

today I realized that I was passing a object around between my React components and it was producing two not wanted effects:
1- A useEffect that was listening to it was being trigger on every re-render.
2- Of course, there was many re-renders.

So, I tried to solve, first by using a **custom useEffect that was deep comparing** the object:

> [use-deep-compare-effect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-deep-compare-effect)

It worked great, by the way thanks to [kentcddodds](https://www.npmjs.com/~kentcdodds) for this resource.

But it is a patch to solve something that is not working finde in my code. So, I have started checking about React.memo and how to compare my nextProps in a functional component. I saw many functions online, but none was offering the **flexibility** to be use for every component and choose how to compare each props.

I created this function, I have done it **the most efficient** I can and I would like to ask you guys what do you think. I am sure you have ideas to improve it.

```
import deepEqual from 'deep-equal';
import { pick } from 'lodash';

/** Get difference between two arrays
 * @param  {} a1
 * @param  {} a2
 */
const getDiffArrays = (a1, a2) => {
    const a = [];
    const diff = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        a[a1[i]] = true;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
        if (a[a2[i]]) {
            delete a[a2[i]];
        } else {
            a[a2[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    for (const k in a) {
        diff.push(k);
    }

    return diff;
};

/**
 *  Return array with unique elements.
 *  ! How efficient is it? This is a function that is intensively used. Get
 * @param  {} arr
 */
const getDistinctKeysArray = (obj1, obj2) => [
    ...new Set([...Object.keys(obj1), ...Object.keys(obj2)]),
];

const compare = (obj1, obj2, compareFunc) => {
    let res = true;
    const keys = Object.keys(obj1);
    for (let key = 0; res && res < keys.length; key++) {
        res = compareFunc(obj1[keys[key]], obj2[keys[key]]);
    }
    return res;
};

/**
 * Shallow comparison
 *
 * @param  {} obj1
 * @param  {} obj2
 */
const compareShallow = (obj1, obj2) => obj1 === obj2;

/**
 * Fast object comparison. It use JSON.stringfy. The problem is that is the order of the props change it
 * will return false, between others
 * @param  {} obj1
 * @param  {} obj2
 */
const compareFastDeep = (obj1, obj2) =>
    JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);
/**
 *  Function to compare object with flexibility.
 * @param  {} obj1
 * @param  {} obj2
 * @param  {} keysCompareFullDeep array keys that are going to be compare using a full deep method that is slowers but effective
 * @param  {} keysCompareFastDeep array keys that are going to be compare using a fast deep method that is not fully effective
 */
const compareHelper = (
    prevProps,
    nextProps,
    keysCompareFullDeep = [],
    keysCompareFastDeep = []
) => {
    // Get keys for shallow compare
    const keysCompareShallow = getDiffArrays(
        getDistinctKeysArray(Object.keys(prevProps), Object.keys(nextProps)),
        getDistinctKeysArray(keysCompareFastDeep, keysCompareFullDeep)
    );
    console.log(keysCompareShallow);
    // Compare shallow
    let res = compare(
        pick(prevProps, keysCompareShallow),
        pick(nextProps, keysCompareShallow),
        compareShallow
    );
    console.log(res);

    // Compare deep fast
    res = res
        ? compareFastDeep(
              pick(prevProps, keysCompareFastDeep),
              pick(nextProps, keysCompareFastDeep)
          )
        : res;
    console.log(res);

    // Compare deep full
    res = res
        ? deepEqual(
              pick(prevProps, keysCompareFullDeep),
              pick(nextProps, keysCompareFullDeep)
          )
        : res;
    console.log(res);
    return res;
};

export { compareHelper };
```

And the usage:

```
SearcherComponent.propTypes = {
    cars: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    filters: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    mainFilters: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    options: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    onFilterChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onFilterDelete: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onShowMoreFilters: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    showMoreFilters: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    addToFavorite: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deleteFavorite: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onSaveFilterList: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    cleanFilterList: PropTypes.func,
    chatRequest: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    goToCarExtendedInfo: PropTypes.func,
    pagination: PropTypes.shape({
        loading: PropTypes.bool,
        setPaginationInfo: PropTypes.func,
        sortBy: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        setSortBy: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        pagination: PropTypes.object,
    }),
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};
const Searcher = React.memo(SearcherComponent, (prev, next) =>
    compareHelper(prev, next, ['pagination', 'cars', 'filters'], [])
);
export { Searcher as SearcherComponent };
```

I know the code is a little bit messy, I am testing several implementations yet.

If we get a good order of efficiency I plan to create a public npm package with it.

Please if anyone knows if it makes sense, and how to make it faster tell me. If considering changing [deep-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal) by [fast-deep-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-deep-equal)

Comment: You could also check the prop being passed and why it keeps changing. There is no relevant information in your question about where that prop comes from and how it's being passed along but there probably is a far easier solution to this.

Comment: @HMR I just want to have a way efficient function to use with React.memo